# Lock analyser for Java application

Tags: java, locking, analysis, sun

I have two versions of a Java application which use different concurrency logic.
I want to analyze and compare their performance (such amount of time a lock was acquired etc.) so that I can use the better one.

I found out a tool IBM Lock Analyzer for Java but it is neither open source nor JDK version independent.
It requires an IBM®-supplied Java™ SDK or JRE.

Another tool also from IBM is Multicore Software Development Kit and has the following problem

> "The testing and analysis tool of MSDK
>   runs on Sun JDK, except the lock
>   analysis tool. The performance tool
>   requires an IBM JDK."

So can anybody recommend any such lock analysis tool which works with Sun/Oracle Java?

Comment: I believe YourKit will do this for Oracle Java. Its not free either but you can get an eval license.

Comment: Thanks, looking into YourKit to see if it satisfy my requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a trick I've used a number of times to find lock contention in production environments from the command line:

```
watch -n1 'jstack [pid] | grep -A 1 BLOCKED | grep -v BLOCKED | grep -v \\-\\-'
```

Not only is it free, there's virtually no overhead. It won't give you stats or a nice UI of course, however it makes real-time locking issues obvious in a visual way. Essentially this is sampling every second to find blocked threads. With enough server load you should be able to make a comparison.

[YourKit](http://yourkit.com/) is a good commercial option.

Comment: I'll be looking into YourKit. BTW your method is for linux machines only and I forgot to mention that we have both linux and windows applications which we might need to analyse.

Comment: Ah, ok. Two things to consider then if you're interested in the inexpensive approach to looking for lock contention under load: 1) you could install Cygwin to run the command I suggested or 2) you could still analyze on Linux the application you plan to deploy on Windows. It is Java after all :)