# Mac.getInstance() for HmacSHA1 taking ages to execute

Tags: java, hmacsha1

I've recently ran into a deployment issue with a call to `Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1")`.
It can take up to 10 minutes to execute that single call on this specific server, whilst on other machines its execution is instant.

CPU usage also spikes during the call.

Here's a bit of details on the server:

- **OS:** CentOS 5.6 Final (kernel 2.6.35.8-16, i686);
- **JVM:** Sun's JDK 1.6.0_25 (32bit);
- **CPU:** Intel Core2 Duo CPU (E8400@3.00GHz);
- **Mem:** 2GB of RAM;
- Dedicated physical server.

Any clues on what might be the problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you're low on system entropy for secure random numbers. See this page to check: [Check available entropy in Linux](http://rackerhacker.com/2007/07/01/check-available-entropy-in-linux/). And this question has answers to consider: [How to solve performance problem with Java SecureRandom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137212/how-to-solve-performance-problem-with-java-securerandom) In particular this Java option should help you:

```
-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom
```

It's much faster, but slightly less secure.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be related to entropy. I installed rng-utils and ran the the rngd, available entropy jumped from 150ish to 1500-2000. I kind of fixed the problem yesterday by switching to OpenJDK... Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, I see you did say that the CPU usage spikes. Have you tried profiling it on that server? One easy way to check is just watch jstack and see which threads are frequently in a `RUNNABLE` state. See this answer for the command I typically use, just replace `BLOCKED` with `RUNNABLE` since you're seeing CPU spikes instead of blocking issues: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5390317/lock-analyser-for-java-application/5390478#5390478

Comment: jstack hangs for as long as the call to `Mac.getInstance()` runs. I did try calling it with `jstack -F <pid>` and here's a couple of outputs I grabbed: http://d.pr/UVV6 and http://d.pr/o0dK. I'll have to wait a bit before investigating any further, since after a couple of executions it stops hanging and runs normally -- seems to have some caching effect.

Comment: Sun's (Oracle) JVM is acting really weird; other than taking ages on that `getInstance()` call, the process randomly dies and I can't even find the crash logs. I'm sticking with OpenJDK for now; thanks for the hints!