# Java Mac.getInstance for HmacSHA1 slow

Tags: java, macos, random, cryptography, hmac

I'm running the following Java program on a Macbook Air running OSX 10.9.4, 1.7GHz i7, 8GB memory. I have the Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) installed.

```
import javax.crypto.Mac;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
  }
}
```

Running this simple program results in a run time of over 5 seconds!

```
$ javac -version
javac 1.7.0_45
$ javac Main.java
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
$ time java Main

real    0m5.326s
user    0m0.390s
sys     0m0.033s
```

I've done a bunch of searching but haven't found much in the way of workarounds or explanation.

- [Mac.getInstance() for HmacSHA1 taking ages to execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142382/mac-getinstance-for-hmacsha1-taking-ages-to-execute)

  This sounds similar to my problem, but all sources I've read indicate that `/dev/random` and `/dev/urandom` are the same on OSX.
- [How to solve performance problem with Java SecureRandom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137212/how-to-solve-performance-problem-with-java-securerandom)

  Again, discussions about SecureRandom's source of randomness, but doesn't seem to apply to OSX.

Has anyone heard of this problem before? Or know of a way for me to debug what's going on? It's really frustrating to take a 5 second penalty to your unit tests when they've been instantaneous up until now.

**Edit:**
Here's timing inside the program and the list of security providers:

```
import java.security.Provider;
import java.security.Security;
import javax.crypto.Mac;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    for (Provider p: Security.getProviders()) {
        System.out.println(p.getName() + " " + p.getVersion() + " " + p.getInfo());
    }
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - start + "ms");
  }
}

$ java Main
SUN 1.7 SUN (DSA key/parameter generation; DSA signing; SHA-1, MD5 digests; SecureRandom; X.509 certificates; JKS keystore; PKIX CertPathValidator; PKIX CertPathBuilder; LDAP, Collection CertStores, JavaPolicy Policy; JavaLoginConfig Configuration)
SunRsaSign 1.7 Sun RSA signature provider
SunEC 1.7 Sun Elliptic Curve provider (EC, ECDSA, ECDH)
SunJSSE 1.7 Sun JSSE provider(PKCS12, SunX509 key/trust factories, SSLv3, TLSv1)
SunJCE 1.7 SunJCE Provider (implements RSA, DES, Triple DES, AES, Blowfish, ARCFOUR, RC2, PBE, Diffie-Hellman, HMAC)
SunJGSS 1.7 Sun (Kerberos v5, SPNEGO)
SunSASL 1.7 Sun SASL provider(implements client mechanisms for: DIGEST-MD5, GSSAPI, EXTERNAL, PLAIN, CRAM-MD5, NTLM; server mechanisms for: DIGEST-MD5, GSSAPI, CRAM-MD5, NTLM)
XMLDSig 1.0 XMLDSig (DOM XMLSignatureFactory; DOM KeyInfoFactory)
SunPCSC 1.7 Sun PC/SC provider
Apple 1.1 Apple Provider
5224ms
```

**Edit 2:**

Figured out how to run [HPROF](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/samples/hprof.html) on the code.

```
$ java -agentlib:hprof=cpu=times Main
$ cat java.hprof.txt
...
TRACE 308670:
java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:Unknown line)
java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:Unknown line)
java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:Unknown line)
javax.crypto.JarVerifier.getSystemEntropy(JarVerifier.java:Unknown line)
...
CPU TIME (ms) BEGIN (total = 6680) Sat Aug 16 05:59:39 2014
rank   self  accum   count trace method
   1 74.87% 74.87%       1 308670 java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr
...
```

So, it appears that for some reason the JarVerifier is trying to get entropy from the system and this is causing the program to spend 5 seconds in InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr...

**Edit 3:**

Updating Java to "1.7.0_67" does not fix the problem.

Comment: I'm running with OSX 10.9.3 on a 2009 iMac and it takes 0.148 seconds to run this code. To ensure you're measuring the right thing, add some time measurements using `System.currentTimeMillis()` *inside* your Java program, so you're not measuring your JVM startup time. Because .. your problem could be a faulty or heavily fragmented disk that causes your JVM to start up slowly.

Comment: Edited to add timing inside the program.

Comment: Could you list the providers you have installed when running that program (`Security.getProviders()`), they are in order of priority.

Comment: Edited to add printing of the list of security providers. Thank you for asking, you reminded me that I do have the Java Crypto Extension installed.

Comment: Vexing. No specific provider that should take a long time. No other libs with large static initializers (e.g. Bouncy Castle in the classpath)? The code exits almost immediately on my Linux system as well. Compare with a fresh install otherwise, just to see if there are any side effects.

Comment: Is there a ten-second delay if you duplicate the `Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");` line, or does the delay only occur the first time you invoke that method?

Comment: No significant additional time is added when duplicating the getInstance call. However, owlstead inspired me to figure out a profiler and I've added an edit above with the apparent culprit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've found a solution. As can be seen in **Edit 2**, `Mac.getInstance()` appears to call `javax.crypto.JarVerifier.getSystemEntropy()`, which eventually calls `java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost()`. According to [this article](http://blog.leon-rosenberg.net/2012/08/oracle-kills-getlocalhost-on-macos-x-in.html), Java 7 changed the way `InetAddress` looks for local host. For some reason, this causes my machine to `lookupAllHostAddr`, which takes ~5 seconds to finish.

One of the comments on the article lists the solution which worked for me, which was to add my hostname to `/etc/hosts`. The following:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
fe80::1%lo0     localhost
```

changes to

```
127.0.0.1       localhost     <replace-me>.local
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
fe80::1%lo0     localhost
```

After the change to the hosts file, my time is back to a reasonable 200ms.

```
$ time java Main

real    0m0.242s
user    0m0.379s
sys 0m0.034s
```

Comment: +1, you did an excellent job tracking this down. I was also looking at the bytecode and getSystemEntropy() does other things that can slow you down, like if you have a million files in your temp directory (property "java.io.tmpdir").

Comment: The java.io.tmpdir issue mentioned by @GregS is one I've bumped into many times.  Need to keep files from building up here or you will face this issue.

Comment: is the value of  <replace-me> should be command `hostname` output?